# substitution of a word with two words and a space using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to substitute a word using sed with two words. For example I'm using:

```
sed s/TITLE/New Title/ old.txt > new.txt
```

However, when I run the command the following populates:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command
```

Any help would be of great appreciation. I've searched everywhere without any clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing quotes. You need to wrap the substitution portion inside quotes like:

```
sed 's/TITLE/New Title/' old.txt > new.txt
```

If you are using variables as part of substitution, you'll need to use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` to allow variables to interpolate.

Take a look at `sed` man page and explore `-i` option which allows you to make `in-place` changes.

Comment: I'm using this in a script, when I add the quotes ' it doesn't read my input. for example:

read NEWTITLE
sed 's/TITLE/$NEWTITLE/'

returns with $NEWTITLE. If I run the command in the CLI it runs as desired, with New Title. However, when executing the script it returns with $NEWTITLE. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3534203 As I stated in my answer, if you are trying to use variables for search and replacement, use double quotes.

Comment: It worked! Sorry for the misread, thanks for your help! Switching from ' to " resolved the issue.